# What should be the right preposition?

Tags: prepositions

I'm trying to make a sentence:

> I basically work in/at/on cold-iron development field

I mean that I explaining to someone my professional field (what I do for living), but not sure about the preposition. What would you say?

Comment: My formulation would be I work in the technical field of cold iron development. (I'm concerned with technical research.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I work in the cold-iron development field.

is what I would say if I did that for a living.

> I work in the software development industry.

is what I, personally, would say.

"At" and "on" don't work at all in this context.
I'm no English teacher, so if someone else has a method for learning the meaning/usage of prepositions I would be glad if they were to post it. Using the correct preposition in the correct place is one of the harder skills to master in English, though. "I work in [whatever field]" is the proper expression. "At" is usually used in regards to a place or time, and "on" is usually used when you're talking about a tangible object ("on the sofa"). "In" can refer to being inside of something, like a house, but it's very commonly also used to refer to a topic or idea. "He's interested in physics," etc.

Comment: No, I just needed to know the correct preposition, thank you.

Comment: Heh, that's why I always put my ramblings at the bottom of an answer.

Comment: @Dmitry Bundin - 'at' could be used like "I work at a cold-iron development lab.", and 'on' could be used like "I work on cold-iron development." I don't actually know what cold-iron development is though, so you might want to explain that as well.

Answer (score 4):

'In' is the correct preposition here. For example:

> I work in IT.
>
> I work in healthcare.
>
> I work in academia.
>
> I work in cold-iron development.

In cases where you want to use 'field' after the profession, you'll also need to use 'the' as an article. For example:

> I work in the healthcare field.

To me, "I work in the cold-iron development field" sounds a bit odd, but that may be because I am not familiar with it.